# stroll.js not seeming to work even though i've included and bound it

Tags: javascript, stroll.js

I am using stroll.js to add CSS transforms to a long list while the user scrolls through it.

[Here is a link to it on github.](https://github.com/hakimel/stroll.js)

I included the stroll.js file, bounded it to the list, and added the class of the type of effect to the list, but it doesn't seem to be working.

I'd appreciate any help in getting it to work.

Here is a live example of the page where it is not working: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/270523/help/stroll/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add css with transformations http://lab.hakim.se/scroll-effects/css/stroll.css + styles from this gist: https://gist.github.com/a-ignatov-parc/5252292

Comment: I have added that. It is the minifed version. If you search for stroll.min.css in my view-source-code you should find it.

However all that does is transform the last <li> in the list. Scroll down to the end of the list and you will see it transformed.

Comment: @IMUXIxD still you missing some styles. See update to my answer